# use more than one meta key in query using posts_where in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Here I want to add query for more then one meta key as here:

```
$where .= " AND meta_key='order_assign_delivery_date' AND meta_value LIKE '0000%' And meta_key='order_assign_data' AND meta_value=0";
```

so now how to do this?

above query not working and that's obvious

Please guide me how to use more than one meta_key in same query in posts_where filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to set up two postmeta using `custom_posts_join` filter

```
function custom_posts_join($join){
 global $wpdb;
 $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as meta_1 ON $wpdb->posts.ID = meta_1.post_id LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as meta_2 ON $wpdb->posts.ID = meta_2.post_id";
 return $join;
}
add_filter( 'posts_join' , 'custom_posts_join');
```

And then you can now set the posts_where

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
       $where .= " AND meta_1.meta_key='order_assign_delivery_date' AND meta_1.meta_value LIKE '0000%' And meta_2.meta_key='order_assign_data' AND meta_2.meta_value=0";
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Any idea how you can return multiple meta_key and meta_value this way?