# Wordpress Custom Query Doesnot return result

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, join

The following query doesnot return any result even though there is a publish date and expiry date in the database

```
SELECT wposts.* 
FROM qit_posts wposts INNER JOIN qit_postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
WHERE wposts.post_type IN ('ad_listing') AND 
wpostmeta.meta_key ='cp_publish_date' 
      AND wpostmeta.meta_value <= '2013-12-10' 
      AND wpostmeta.meta_key ='cp_expiry_date' 
      AND wpostmeta.meta_value >= '2013-12-10'
```

in the database table there is a post , which has a meta field cp_publish_date with value 2013-12-08 and cp_expiry_date 2013-12-31
The query should return that particular raw, but it doesnot  return it, does anyone have idea for this, what ,might be the problem, here there is no problem in the date format in comparing, i am handling it properly

Comment: I also find some threads same what I faced in two forum, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312061/use-more-than-one-meta-key-in-query-using-posts-where-in-wordpress
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111456/posts-where-fails-with-more-than-one-custom-field-in-query

and without a right answer

Answer (score 0):

As i see , ur looking in wpostmeta.meta_key but already you ar using "AND " parameter ur ar using it with two diffirent value.

```
wpostmeta.meta_key ='cp_publish_date'  AND AND wpostmeta.meta_key ='cp_expiry_date'
```

you should use "or" parameter.

i think you want to do that;

```
SELECT wposts.* 
FROM qit_posts wposts INNER JOIN qit_postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
WHERE wposts.post_type IN ('ad_listing') AND (
wpostmeta.meta_key ='cp_publish_date' 
      AND wpostmeta.meta_value <= '2013-12-10' ) OR
       (wpostmeta.meta_key ='cp_expiry_date' 
      AND wpostmeta.meta_value >= '2013-12-10' )
```

Take it easy

Comment: You ar querying to mysql that ; "lets give me posts where meta_key is 'cp_publish_date' and 'cp_expiry_date' it can be true when thinking as human but not , cuz a column only have one value. if you want to fetch  both cp_publish_date cp_expiry_date u should use "or" parameter . My english not so good so i cant explain very well . I hope u understood. If u dont u can look http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Advanced_MySQL_Data_Filtering_-_AND,_OR,_NOT_and_IN

Comment: Arslan,can you please clarify bit why should I use or condition, i should get all posts bet ween publish and expiry, thats my requirement, if I use or condition it wont give the correct result, logical error, becuase I have two post , 1 post has publish date 2013-12-08 and other post publish date is 2013-12-12 , if I use or query Its going to return both record, because each post expiry date is greater than 2013-12-10 (2013-12-30), our or condition becomes true in that case, I think I have to solve this with sub query, is it so, or do you know any other ways to solve this problem

Comment: as i understood u want to get wpostmeta.meta_value BETWEEN "2013-12-10" and "2013-12-10",right ? 

Or , u want to fetch daha if meta_key == 'cp_publish_date' fetch meta_value is <= '2013-12-10' or if wp_meta_key == 'cp_expiry_date' fetch meta_value is >= '2013-12-10'

Comment: I want to fetch records, that publish and expiry date between current date, and note here publish and expiry date are two different value of meta key

Comment: u want to fetch daha if meta_key == 'cp_publish_date' fetch meta_value is <= '2013-12-10' or if wp_meta_key == 'cp_expiry_date' fetch meta_value is >= '2013-12-10', right?

Comment: Yes that is what I wanted,

(meta_key == 'cp_publish_date' and <= '2013-12-10' )and( wp_meta_key == 'cp_expiry_date' fetch meta_value is >= '2013-12-10')

Answer (score 0):

try this one by using `STR_TO_DATE(str,format)` wp's `meta_value` is of type text you need to convert it to date as per your desired date format, also you need to join `qit_postmeta` two times for two different keys

```
SELECT wposts.* 
FROM qit_posts wposts 
INNER JOIN qit_postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
INNER JOIN qit_postmeta wpostmeta2 ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
WHERE wposts.post_type IN ('ad_listing') 
AND  wpostmeta.meta_key ='cp_publish_date' 
AND STR_TO_DATE(wpostmeta.meta_value,'%d %M,%Y') <= '2013-12-10' 
AND wpostmeta2.meta_key ='cp_expiry_date' 
AND STR_TO_DATE(wpostmeta2.meta_value,'%d %Y,%Y') >= '2013-12-10'
GROUP BY wposts.ID
```

[**STR_TO_DATE(str,format)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: M Khalid junaid, thank you for you reply, but I think i dont have to convert string in to date format, as I know that PHP will handle comparison as long as the date string is in the yy-mm-dd format, do you have more idea on this

Comment: @MohamedAkram Its not  php side comparison you are running mysql query and mysql needs the date type column to compare is this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Using `OR` will not help. Try this:

```
SELECT wposts.* 
FROM qit_posts wposts 
JOIN (
  SELECT post_id
  FROM qit_postmeta
  GROUP BY post_id
  HAVING SUM(
    CASE 
     WHEN meta_key ='cp_publish_date' AND meta_value <= '2013-12-10' THEN 1
     WHEN meta_key ='cp_expiry_date' AND meta_value >= '2013-12-10' THEN 1
     ELSE 0
    END 
    ) = 2
  ) wpostmeta
ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
WHERE wposts.post_type IN ('ad_listing')
```